# How to make the VT display chinese characters?

Tags: tty

When I use the VT (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>),it will only display replacement characters for chinese, but from the alternative installation CD I can see, that it's actually possible to display chinese in the VT. How to enable this?

Comment: I booted into a chinese livecd. I hit ctl-alt-f1 to get to the console, and found it **did not display chinese characters**. I'm using a 10.10 ubuntu desktop iso. I had to install and run fbiterm to get the console to show chinese. Is your experience different? How so?

Comment: Also, when you installed ubuntu, did you install in english, or chinese? Please run `locale` and add it's output to your question.

Comment: I installed the german version of ubuntu. locale days `de_DE.utf8` everywhere.

Answer (score 5):

I booted the 10.10 32-bit Ubuntu livecd, and chose what I'm pretty sure is simplified chinese (second to last option on the language menu). After it booted into the trial environment, I hit <kbd>ctl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>f1</kbd>, typed `ls`, and was rewarded with diamonds instead of chinese. I conclude Ubuntu does not include chinese support for console/tty. Otoh, everything works wonderfully inside Gnome.

Fortunately, you can add chinese tty support. Install `fbiterm` and run it on a tty. It's a frame buffer that can deal with non-latin characters. I don't know yet how to make fbiterm used by default.

@FUZxxl, running fbiterm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 10.10 in VirtualBox gives me your error `Frame buffer device /dev/fb0: Open error`. I found an [UbuntuForum.org thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=652038) that suggests you need to load the kernel module that allows frame buffers. It's a bit old..here's what I did:

1. Edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`. Add to the end of the file on separate lines: `fbcon` and `vesafb`.
2. Edit `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer` and uncomment `vesafb`.
3. Run: `sudo update-initramfs -u -k all`.
4. Make sure you have a vga line set in `/etc/default/grub`. Example: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="vga=0x314"`
5. Run `update-grub`.

Now you can reboot and run `fbiterm` at the virtual console.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. To you know, which solution is used by the ubuntu alternate installer?

Comment: Hm... Very bad. They all don't work on my machine. Maybe it's an issue with the nvidia driver.

Comment: First, the screen goes black.

Comment: Than nothing happens. If you change to another VT and back, there appears another message: Frame buffer device /dev/fb0: Open error. I guess it's something about the nVidia driver (as always...)

Comment: I wouldn't give up yet. I reproduced the error without using an nvidia gfx driver.

Comment: I tried all your steps, but nothing happens. Still the same problem. I'm depressed.

Comment: I tried your tutorial, but still nothing changes. What am I doing wrong???

Comment: OK. Thanks for all the help. I'm going to assign this bounty to you now, as I have no time tomorrow. I'm very sad it doesn't works on my machine.

Comment: I'm still trying to think why it wouldn't work for you. All I can come up with is maybe you don't have framebuffer support in your kernel. But you would've had to manually accomplish this, and I assume you're running a stock Ubuntu kernel?

Comment: @djeikyb: Sorry for the delay. I had to do some other things in the meanwhile. Yes, it's the ubuntu tock kernel. `uname -r` says *2.6.35-28-generic*.

Comment: The problem is that VT cannot display chinese characters but still insist using a zh locale. Why not falling back to en locale automatically? It's really not about framebuffer, it's about the designed's rotted mind.

Comment: Just one note, I have to install `fbterm` rather than `fbiterm`. Probably a typo?

Comment: @dibery i believe it's an abbreviation pronounced Frame Buffered Internationalized Terminal. But I do hope that by now unicode is supported by default instead of requiring esoteric packages.

Answer (score 0):

I think, true "text mode" VT uses text video mode, so it's limited to 256/512 different chars at the same time. I don't know too much about the Chinese language, but I guess it has much more "letters" that other languages having an "alphabet" with 26 letters or so :) Though, I think Ubuntu uses framebuffer VT console (not text VGA mode based), so maybe in theory it's possible to do ...

Comment: Do you know Clonezilla? If you start it, it will ask you for language settings. For instance, it will say 正體中文. As you can clearly see, clonezilla uses something VT-alike, so it couldn't be that difficult.

Comment: Looking at `ps -e|grep fb`, `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-framebuffer.conf`, and `lsmod|grep fb`, Ubuntu does **not** use a framebuffer. Confirmed with 10.04 and 10.10.