# How to display characters in (virtualbox) TTY?

Tags: virtualbox, language-support, locale

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 in VirtualBox, but can't get Chinese chars to display correctly. Here's what chars that should be Chinese look like:

[image]

I've done everything I could, including:

```
sudo apt-get -y install `check-language-support -l zh_CN`
```

Set `/var/lib/locales/supported.d/local` to

```
zh_CN.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

And change `/etc/default/locale`.

What should I do then?

Comment: Are you using a TTY in virtualbox (not a terminal)?

Comment: It's a TTY. I didn't install GUI.

Comment: Which fonts for rendering Chinese have you installed?

Comment: I don't think the TTY consoles support characters as they are supposed to be for emeregency use or something. You could install a light desktop such as Xfce or LXDE and use a terminal emulator to get character support.

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/23610/how-to-enable-unicode-support-in-a-tty

Comment: @chaskes Thx, but unicode_start doesn't seem to work...

Comment: @Wilf I think you're right.

Comment: I'm not sure but support may be available https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Fonts#Previewing_and_testing http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/6.2/chapter07/console.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link [How to make the VT display chinese characters?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25187/how-to-make-the-vt-display-chinese-characters)

Which might be useful to you. Check it out and tell me.

Comment: Cool, but it seems a little complicated...

Answer (score 0):

Just reconfigure your console:

```
sudo dpkg --reconfigure console-setup
```